# Celsius to Fahnrenheit and Fahrenheit to Celsius using 3 methods

Tags: java

My assignment is to make a simple Celsius to Fahrenheit or Fahrenheit to Celsius converter. My lab teacher kind of walked me through most of it, but did a bad job at explaining things. I know what most of it does and how it interacts, and the code has 0 errors but does not properly do the conversions. I will post the code, and will //comment on the parts that I donot understand, but what I really need is for someone to explain the parts that I do not understand, and it'd be awesome to fix the script so that it performs properly. I will comment on the parts I do not understand.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class ExerciseOne
 {
public static void main( String[] args ) 
{

    int choice;


    System.out.println( "What would you like to do? \n 1 - Fahnrenheit to Celsius \n 2 - Celsius to Fahrenheit \n 3 - Quit" );
    Scanner dylan = new Scanner(System.in);
    choice = dylan.nextInt();



    if (choice == 1) 
    {
        System.out.println( "What number do you want to convert to Celsius?" );
        float input = dylan.nextFloat();
        float output = ftoC(input);        // I'm kind of confused as to why she told me to put the variable inside of the ();      
        System.out.println(ftoC(input)); //Same here with the variables :(


    }

    if (choice == 2)
    {
        System.out.println( "What number do you want to convert to Fahrenheit?" );
        float input = dylan.nextFloat();
        float output = ctoF(input);
        System.out.println(ctoF(output));
    }

    if (choice == 3) 
    {
        System.out.println( "Exiting application.");
    }

}

public static float ftoC(float f)  //This is a method line, but why is float f inside the parenthesis?
{
    float celsius = (f-32)*(5/9); 
    return celsius;
}

public static float ctoF(float c) //Same thing goes for here
{
    float fahrenheit = (c)*(9/5) + 32;
    return fahrenheit;
}
```

}

Comment: You need to make the `5/9` a float or double to peform "real division", like you learned in school. Otherwise, Java will drop the remainder (aka the fraction). Sometimes, this will come out to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
float output = ftoC(input);        // I'm kind of confused as to why she told me to put the variable inside of the ();
```

This is so you can pass the variable to the function `ftoC`.

```
System.out.println(ftoC(input)); //Same here with the variables :(
```

Same as above. How else will the data get to the function or method?

`public static float ftoC(float f)  //This is a method line, but why is float f inside the parenthesis?`

Because you have to tell the program what your data type is so it knows how to lay it out in memory. Otherwise, it has no idea how big you want your data type to be in memory. Also, if you were to pass an `int` to a method that expects `float`, the program would exhibit different behavior.

Comment: Thank you GI Joe, you were extremely helpful in the solving of my issue. I have one last question, I completed ExerciseOne and the second Exercise is asking me to: Add a line in the main that calls the ftoC method and passes as its argument the variable declared in step 2.

I set double var = 0;
And I would like to know how to call the method. Would it be something similiar to this WITHIN the main method?

double var = 0;
  
public static float ftoC(double var);

Comment: Assuming you set `var` to something other than `0` later on, then yes. If you can't figure it out, you should ask another question. But I think you need to do some research and reading in a book on Java.

Comment: Well the exercise tells me this: 


In the main method declare a variable of type
double
and initialize it to
a value.
3. Add a line in the main that calls the
fToC
method and passes as its
argument the variable declared in step 2.
4. Save and try to compile the program. Don
’
t worry about add
ing
or
committing
to the Git repository
. This exercise will not be graded.
5.
When you try to compile you should get the following error message:
>
TempConverter.java:16: fToC(float) in TempConverter cannot be applied
>
to (double)
>
float temp = fToC( test );
>
^
>
1 error

Comment: The purpose is to get an error, then fix it in another exercise. I set double var = 0; and called the method using public static float ftoC(double var){

Comment: However, I am getting this error instead, and I've tried changing things up but to no avail.

C:\Users\Dylan\Desktop\lab5>javac ExerciseTwo.java
ExerciseTwo.java:16: error: method ftoC in class ExerciseTwo cannot be applied t
o given types;
                float temp = ftoC( var );
                             ^
  required: float
  found: double
  reason: actual argument double cannot be converted to float by method invocati
on conversion
1 error

Comment: `ftoC(float x)` needs to be changed to `ftoC(double x)` for instance.

Answer (score 2):

Taking one question at a time...

```
float output = ftoC(input); // I'm kind of confused as to why she told me to
```

put the variable inside of the ();

Here `ftoC` is a method and `input` is being passed to it

```
System.out.println(ftoC(input)); //Same here with the variables :(
```

You are calling the method *again*. Pointless. Just print the result from the previous call:

```
System.out.println(output);
```

Further, I would change these lines:

```
float input = dylan.nextFloat();
float output = ftoC(input);
System.out.println(output);
```

To just:

```
System.out.println(ftoC(dylan.nextFloat()));
```

You don't need those local variables, just pass each return value straight into the next method.

---

```
public static float ftoC(float f)  //This is a method line, but why is float f inside the parenthesis?
```

Parameters (if any) are declared in brackets, as a type followed by a parameter name. Here we have a `float` parameter called `f`

---

But there are several bugs. In java, integer division results in an integer result, which means truncating the non-whole number part, so `5/9` is the `int` `0`. But to fix it, just remove the brackets!:

```
public static float ftoC(float f) {
    return (f-32)*5/9; 
}
```

By removing the brackets, the problem is fixed because in java, if *one* of the operands is `float` and the other `int`, the result is `float`. This calculation first subtracts an `int` from a `float` - giving a `float`. It then multiplies by the `int` `5` - giving a `float`. It then divides by the `int` `9` - giving a `float`!

Notice too that I didn't bother with the local variable - just return the calculation. Less code is good.

Comment: The last part makes total logical sense, it just many people don't think of it that way. Put it on paper and you see why this is right.

Answer (score 1):

For starters this doesn't do what you expect:

```
(f-32)*(5/9);
```

5/9 is performed as an integer division, so it equates to 0. anything multiplied by 0 is also 0.
You need to cast the 5 and / or the 9 to float:

```
(f-32)*(5f/9f);
```

Comment: The solution is actually simpler than that :)

Comment: This solved the Fahrenheit to Celsius problem! But for some odd reason, the formula for Celsius to Fahrenheit is not calculating correctly. float fahrenheit = (9/5)*c) + 32; that should give me 68 when I type in 20, but its giving me 84. (9/5)* 20 = 36, 36 + 32 = 68, but for some reason I am getting 84.

Comment: @user3304333: Remove the parentheses around `9/5`... actually remove all the parentheses. You don't need them.